# How to use format post in a pertinent way

Tags: posts, theme-development, post-formats, videos

I need to create a video post for my theme. I want to use post format via:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'video' ) );
```

So it is good, in my single.php I will able to get:

```
if ( has_post_format( 'video' )) {
  echo 'this is the video format';
}
```

But the idea on this video page is to get the URL of the video to replace the feature image (for example) with the video frame.
Can I do this only with "post format" feature? 
Or do I need a homemade dev to add a video url input that display only if the user choose video format?